# Anyone have the control block for the hitechnic color sensors?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g, robotic

I'm just wondering if anyone has a copy of the control block for the hitechnic color sensor v2? I'll take a v1 if you have that because I'm desperate at this point. The downloads page for it is down and my team needs this soon. If you have this or know where it can be found please can you provide the link?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the page listing downloads is down, but direct links to the downloads still work. I believe that this is the file that you're looking for:

https://www.hitechnic.com/upload/306-Color%20Sensor%20V2.zip

Comment: Thanks! OMG YOUR A LIFESAVER! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Hi @rpi-noob and welcome to Bricks! If this has answered your question, you can also click the little tick mark under the votes to "accept" this answer :)