# Seeking HiTechnic Color Sensor V2 control block for EV3-G

Tags: ev3, ev3-g, sensor-colour

I'm looking for the EV3-G control block for the HiTechnic Color Sensor V2, previously distributed by HiTechnic (https://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?key=NCO1038&preadd=action), apparently now distributed by Modern Robotics (https://modernroboticsinc.com/product/hitechnic-nxt-color-sensor-v2/).

Many websites and online installation guides claim that the block is available from the downloads and support website from the original supplier (https://www.hitechnic.com/downloadnew.php?category=38).  However, that site has been down for at least the past week and perhaps longer.  Emails to both HiTechnic and Modern Robotics have gone unanswered, thus it appears that the sites are no longer maintained.  :-(

A similar question was recently asked and answered ([Anyone have the control block for the hitechnic color sensors?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/anyone-have-the-control-block-for-the-hitechnic-color-sensors)), however, the direct download link suggested there (https://www.hitechnic.com/upload/306-Color%20Sensor%20V2.zip) is for the older NXT control block only.  Unfortunately, the NXT block is not compatible with EV3-G and the current EV3 brick.  I'm seeking the EV3 block, not the NXT block.

I hope that someone here can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitechnic.com now points to modernroboticsinc.com. You can find the Hitechnic EV3 color sensor block here:

https://modernroboticsinc.com/download/hitechnic-ev3-color-sensor-block/

All available downloads are available and searchable here:

https://modernroboticsinc.com/downloads/

Comment: It seems like the download is no longer working. Is there anyone who has the file and can mirror it somewhere?

Comment: @AstroGD I've updated the links in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!  The answer from jncraton did the trick.

Summary: the direct download for the EV3 sensor block for the HiTechnic Color Sensor V2 is here:
https://www.hitechnic.com/upload/545-HiTechnicEV3Color.zip

The zip archive includes three files: 
(1) instructions (HTColorREADME.txt)
(2) the control block (HTColor.ev3b)
(3) a sample file demonstrating use of the control block (ViewColor.ev3)
All three worked like a charm.

The instructions above for locating arbitrary HiTechnic files worked well also.  This technique will be useful to others seeking programming blocks for other HiTechnic sensors.